# How to apply stdout.flush function to input prompt?

Tags: python

I'm new to coding and have started with Python and want to create a simple text-based game, I've stumbled at the first hurdle. I figured out how to incorporate a "typewriter" style progression to my text, but only for text written to the screen.

```
for char in "Welcome to my first game!\n": 
    print(char, end='') 
    sys.stdout.flush() 
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

If I wanted to do the same for the `input` function's prompt, such as this:

```
input("What is your name? \n")
```

How would I go about it?

Is there also a way to apply this to the whole program instead of every time I want to print a line?

Comment: You could print it the same way as above (not including a newline), and then do `input` with an empty prompt.

Comment: Maybe others get it, but I can't picture what you mean by "a label of an input function".  Do you mean the text of a prompt that asks for input? If so, why is that any different than what you show here?

Comment: Ha!  Sounds like  @alaniwi and I are thinking the same way,  Maybe you just didn't think about the fact that you don't need your prompt text to actually come from the input() call.

Comment: FYI, you don't need to use `sys.stdout.flush()`, you can use `print(char, end='', flush=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a starter. I am just using your own code.

```
def input_flush(): 
    for char in "Welcome to my first game!\nWhat is your name?\n":   
        print(char, end='', flush=True) 
        time.sleep(0.1)
    return input()

name = input_flush()

print("great to see you {}".format(name))
```